# Unable to edit posts with reserved edit characters like *

Tags: discussion, support

Actually I am trying to edit one question in which some part of code snippet is faded out like below :

[image]

I am unable to do it  because special character * is involved in code snippet. Which is reserved special character for question **code edit** .

What change should do to edit it>

Question  link:
[Can we use regular expressions in web.xml URL patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570805/can-we-user-regular-expression-type-patterns-in-web-xml)

Comment: I have added the language hint for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the syntax highlighter to highlight this snippet as XML. You do this by adding a [language hint](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

     <web.xml>
      <filter>
      ...
```

Comment: yeah; but still I am not able handle faded gray code snippet happened because of /*

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev: You must not be applying the language hint correctly. Please edit your question to include your full question text.

Comment: question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570805/can-we-user-regular-expression-type-patterns-in-web-xml